# Ruby on Rails: Long list of migration files, common?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, database-migration

Is having a long list of migration files often common when building a web application? I seem to be adding up a long list of migration files because I keep forgetting or keep thinking of adding an extra column to a 'already' migrated database table.

Answer (score 3):

Having a long list of migration files is normal. It's one of the best features of rails. Think of them as layers(like an onion) that you stack on top of each other. If you add a new column or table and then you decide that you don't want it anymore you can rollback(peel away) the latest changes. As long as you have the migration files you can move back and forth easily(don't recommend moving much but you get the point). REMEMBER DO NOT DELETE migration files once they are raked unless you do a rollback. When you rollback and delete a migration file make absolutely SURE you are at the right layer(rollback point).

why? because for example when someone clones your app and runs your migration file it goes through all the migration files from beginning to end. if something in the middle is messed up or deleted you won't be able to create the database because it goes through ALL the steps. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if you do the migrations correctly it should have to have a long list of migrations. Because every little change you have to do via migration. As you said, proper way is to add a new migration when you need to alter a table.

So as I mentioned I believe having more and more migrations means you are doing it correct. (Because most of the time when you need alterations to to an existing table you simple cannot drop the table and re-create it).

But having said that it always a good idea to run `rake db:migrate` every now and then (for an isolated db) just to make sure your migrations are working as a group.

Answer (score 0):

It may be bad habit, but I migrate down using rake `db:migrate VERSION=0`, then change the respective migration that has (for instance) the users, and finally migrate the database using `rake db:migrate`. That way i have less of a mess, and know exactly which migration does what to what model. It's cleaner, but I guess this technique can be used only at the beginning of the webapp.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One more point to be noted, from rails docs

> If you need to create the application database on another system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
>
> It's strongly recommended to check this file(schema.rb) into your version control system.